# How can I modify the Android Gesture visuals (for on screen gesture detection)?

Tags: android-view, android, android-input-method, android-gesture

Essentially what I'm trying to do is use this gesture functionality as demonstrated below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tG3lzBDMRQQ
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

Except instead of just setting a color, I want to be able to add a variety of visual effects to the lines drawn during a gesture motion.

IE: pulsating thickness / color changing / particle effects like a sparkler-stick firework etc.

Where would one start in attempting such a venture?

edit:   One method I'm considering is to set the gesture color to transparent, but have a separate listener for touches as in some paint-type apps.  And So it simultaneously creatures the gesture and draws the proper image over top of it.  Would this work?  Can the screen be listening for input from two views at once?

Answer (score 0):

GestureOverlayView is a normal view which has the capability to draw on screen. You can simply extend GestureOverlayView and add your custom effects. You can set your custom paint style, or you can override dispatchTouchEvent() to add your own effects while drawing it.